# How to add a qt5 application in a yocto recipe?

Tags: qt, qml, yocto

I would like to know where I'm missing something in my project. In fact, I'm successfully embedding all the files I need in my recipe and all the packages I need (I think). Qt5 is installed in my recipe (I have the meta-qt5 layer) and my app is launching but immediately crashing with this error :

```
QQmlCOmponent : Component is not ready
qml : actionView test for Vid? is null
QQmlComponent : Component is not ready
qml : action imageTest for Image is null
qt.qpa.xcb : xcb_shm_create_segment() failed for size 1228800
Segmentation fault
```

I first thought that these error were here because the binary could not find my qml files. I've made some changes to my recipe so that every needed files are embedded and nothing has changed. Then I thought that I was missing some QtQuick packages like the qml plugin one. I also added it, but the error is still the same. My only last thought is that I'm missing another package or that on the yocto side, reading qrc files is not done in the same way then on the pc side ( my app is working perfectly in Qt Creator using Qt 5.12.3).

PS : I also tested to use the binary of my application made by qt creator in the directory "sent" in the yocto image and it works like in Qt Creator. That is make me thinking that the tree of files deployed in yocto is good (it is the same as in my qt project so that make senses but I'm trying everything I can to debug this problem)

If you have any idea on where these errors could come from, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Are your QML files included in your .qrc file? If  so, they do not need to be deployed to the device at all. What other files would it be looking for?

Comment: Yes I have a qrc which I include in the RESOURCES of my .pro file and also in the SRC_URI of my bb file which contains all the qml files. I also have others qrc files for png files, font files etc and I'm doing the same thing for these qrc files as for the qml one.

Comment: I think I'm missing some packages in my bb recipe file but which one.. In my pro file i have the following line : QT += qml quick gui, what packages should I add in the DEPENDS and RDEPENDS fields of the recipe ?

Comment: EDIT: Problem is solved, I added the qtmultimedia package. Now I have this error : QML Image : Cannot open : qrc:/test.jpg whereas I have this image in my qrc file ...

Comment: Problem solved, now I just need to get through this seg fault ..

     qt.qpa.xcb : xcb_shm_create_segment() failed for size 1228800
     Segmentation fault

Comment: Any luck?  I get this particular error if I run directly on the target.  If I debug from my host, from Qt Creator, I get nothing on the target display and "Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."  Directly from the target though (Rpi), I get the Qt app to display.